# How do I slow the progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coldfusion, drag-and-drop

I have the following code:

```
<td id="drop-files" ondragover="return false;" colspan="2">
    <br />Drag and drop files to be uploaded...<br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" id="iFile" value="" /><input type="hidden" id="numFiles" value="" />
   <div id="progressBar" style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border-radius: 20px; border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 0; text-align: center; background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,96,160) 0%, rgb(32,96,160) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);">0%</div><br />
   <div id="fileCase"></div>
</td>

// Note: The double ## is not a mistake. The code is running under  
// ColdFusion where # is a is reserved character. So ## escapes the #
$(document).ready(function() {
    function pad(number, digits) {
        return Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
    }

    function processFile(file,num,arr){
        var inputRow = "<input type='hidden' value='' id='file_"+pad(arr,3)+"' name='file_"+pad(arr,3)+"' />";
        $("##fileCase").append(inputRow);
        var o = $("##file_"+pad(arr,3));
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                o.val(e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function updateProgress(idx,tot){
        var midPt = Math.floor((idx)/tot*100);
        $("##progressBar").css("background","-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,96,160) 0%, rgb(32,96,160) "+midPt+"%, rgb(255,255,255) "+midPt+"%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%)");
        $("##progressBar").html(midPt+"%");
    }
    // Sets up dataTransfer event
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
    // File Array
    var nameArray = [];
    $("##fileCase").append("<input type='hidden' id='nameArray' value='' name='nameArray'>");

    // Bind drop to drop zone
    $('##drop-files').bind('drop', function(e) {
        var iFile = 0;
        // Prevents element from default function
        e.preventDefault();
        // Grabs list of files
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        var numFiles = files.length;set("numFiles",numFiles);
        $("##progressBar").animate({opacity: 1},500);
        // Loop through files...
        updateProgress(0,numFiles);
        $.each(files, function(index, file) {
            nameArray.push(files[index].name);
            arr = nameArray.length;
            $("##nameArray").val(nameArray.join("|"));
            processFile(files[index],index+1,arr);
            iFile++;set("iFile",iFile);
            //setTimeout("updateProgress("+iFile+","+numFiles+");",250);
            setTimeout("var midPt = Math.floor(get('iFile')/get('numFiles')*100);$('##progressBar').css('background','-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(32,96,160) 0%, rgb(32,96,160) '+midPt+'%, rgb(255,255,255) '+midPt+'%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%)');$('##progressBar').html(midPt+'%');",500)
        });
    });
});
```

It works great, save for one *tiny* little thing. The progress bar seems to shoot up to 100% too quickly. I would rather slow it down a little just so that I can get something that looks like it's doing something thoroughly.

Anyone know how I can slow it down so that we can actually see the progress bar working?

The `set()` and `get()` functions within the code are just quick functions I made to store variables in hidden input form elements to allow the `setTimeout` function to work.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: `$("##progressBar")`? You mean `$("#progressBar")`, right?

Comment: You can slow it down by uploading a bigger file.

Comment: @MattBall, oh, sorry... the ## is because I'm running this within a ColdFusion based environment, and the ## escapes the #... Apologies for not making that clear in the beginning...

Comment: and @ahren, I've tried doing that, but the `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` function has this unique ability to convert the file very quickly into Base 64... What I'm after is something that can put an interval after this conversion, and then do some sort of update to the progress bar...

And try as I may, the timeout on the Timeout statement doesn't seem to work, no matter how large I make that value...

Comment: There are reasons to do this, and even if there weren't, we are not here to question his motives.

Comment: @JustAguy I want to slow it down so that an actual progress bar behavior can be seen, not a 0% one moment and 100% the next... 

If I wanted that, I'd simulate the ding of a microwave oven...

But I've been asked by management to provide a progress bar, and with it shooting straight to 100% when it's processing 20 or so files is not a valid progress bar...

Comment: There is a way it can be done... After Googling for about 45 mins, the following solution was available here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090750/how-to-slow-down-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do this, and why you're doing it by a gradient instead of animating the width of a child which would allow you to use css3 transition delays, but you could easily achieve the delayed effect by just adding a small jquery-delay every time updateProgress() runs.

Just chain it in before updating the css.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/