# JavaScript - slow down a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timeout, settimeout

I have these codes in controller that call webservice using $http get to retrieve some data. Here is the following code:

**UPDATE CODES**:

```
   var boolGetBoothCoords = false;
      BoothDesignatedCoordsService.getBoothDesignatedCoords(strListShortListedBooth[i], 3)

 .then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data
        console.log('data', data.arrBoothDesignatedCoords)
        boothDesignatedCoords = data.arrBoothDesignatedCoords;
        boolGetBoothCoords = true;
})

console.log("boothDesignatedCoords ", boothDesignatedCoords ); // undefined
// And a lot of other codes
```

However, since $http get is asynchronous method, the program will invoke the console log and the codes after immediately and boothDesignatedCoords will be undefined. I do not want that. I want the program to invoke the console log and the codes after ONLY when the webservice consumption is completed. So I did the following using this answer:  [how to slow down a javascript loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090750/how-to-slow-down-a-javascript-loop):

```
    go();
    function go() {
        console.log("hello");

        if (boolGetBoothCoords == false) {
            setTimeout(go, 1000);

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    go()

   console.log("boothDesignatedCoords ", boothDesignatedCoords ); // undefined
   // OTHER CODES that uses variable boothDesignatedCoords will be undefined     as well
```

However, I do not know why it will still invoke the console log but the web service consumption is not completed yet, despite using this method. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: why not to include `console.log` in the last `then` callback, next to `fnProceedOtherTask1()` call?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have updated my question

Comment: still, it's better to print it in the last callback than waiting using `setTimeout`... what happens if the server response takes longer than 1s? it'll be still undefined

Comment: I think i misunderstood how setTimeOut work. Can u please explain to me how the setTimeOut works in this case?

Comment: oh I see what you were trying to do here... I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, so actually you don't really make a difference calling `go` function.

What will happen is:

- call `go()` function
- call `setTimeout` inside the function - that will schedule `go` to be called in (roughly) 1s
- call `console.log` immediately after that

What you probably want is to put your `console.log` in `then` callback like that:

```js
var boolGetBoothCoords = false;
BoothDesignatedCoordsService.getBoothDesignatedCoords(strListShortListedBooth[i], 3)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.data.arrBoothDesignatedCoords;
  })
  .then(function(boothDesignatedCoords) {
    console.log("boothDesignatedCoords ", boothDesignatedCoords );
  });
```

---

The other option (not recommended) would be to put `console.log` in the `else` part of the `if` statement in your `go` function.

In this case, you should also define `boothDesignatedCoords` before the whole code snippet.

Comment: Hi, but there is still another problem if i follow your code. Before .then(function(boothDesignatedCoords) method is invoked, the program already exits the controller

Comment: I guess you are using AngularJS and you want to change your `$scope`... then I'd suggest you should make all the changes to it in the callback as well

Answer (score 1):

The code that suppose to be run after the response, should be invoked after the response.

```
var boolGetBoothCoords = false;

BoothDesignatedCoordsService.getBoothDesignatedCoords(
    strListShortListedBooth[i], 3)

.then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data
    console.log('data', data.arrBoothDesignatedCoords)
    boothDesignatedCoords = data.arrBoothDesignatedCoords;
    boolGetBoothCoords = true;
    codeThatUsesTheResponseData();
});
function codeThatUsesTheResponseData() {
    console.log("boothDesignatedCoords ", boothDesignatedCoords ); // undefined
    // And a lot of other codes
}
```

Comment: Hi, but there is still another problem if i follow your code. Before codeThatUsesTheResponseData method is invoked, the program already exits the controller

Comment: It exits after which line and how? There should be a return, exception or refresh at some point to cause the code not to invoke the next line.